# Using dplyr's mutate function to return relative values within a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr's mutate function to create a new variable that pulls in relative values of an existing variable based on the value of an ifelse statement. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, which will hopefully better illustrate the problem:

```
id  from_date fobs     to_date
 a 1999-01-05    0  1999-01-10
 a 1999-01-10    0  1999-02-14
 a 1999-02-14    1  2013-12-31
 b 1999-03-19    0  1999-03-25
 b 1999-03-25    1  2013-12-31
 c 1999-02-14    0  1999-02-15
 c 1999-02-15    1  2013-12-31
```

The dataset is grouped by ID, and I'm trying to assign to each observation of the "to_date" the next observation's value of the from date where the value of "fobs" is equal to 0, and 2013-12-31 where the value is equal to 1.

This is the code I most recently tried, which isn't working for me, but I hope adequately expresses what I'm trying to accomplish with the dplyr package:

```
qdat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(to_date = ifelse(fobs == 1,as.Date("2013-12-31"),as.Date(lead(qdat$date))))
```

For what it's worth, these are the results of running that code:

```
  id  from_date val fobs to_date
1  a 1999-01-05   5    0      NA
2  a 1999-01-10   9    0      NA
3  a 1999-02-14   4    1   16070
4  b 1999-03-19   7    0      NA
5  b 1999-03-25  14    1   16070
6  c 1999-02-14  10    0      NA
7  c 1999-02-15  11    1   16070
```

I have reviewed the "Hands on dplyr tutorial for faster data manipulation in R" (R-Bloggers), R-Studio's presentation on "The Grammar and Graphics of Data Science," which features additional infomation on dplyr, and other stackoverflow questions about the dplyr package and relative cell references in general, but I have not yet found a way to solve this problem. For the record, I'm also very new to R, so I apologize in advance if I'm overlooking something that seems perfectly obvious to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

qdat %>% group_by(id) %>%
         mutate(to_date = lead(from_date, default = as.Date("2013-12-31")))
```

You can take out the ifelse, as the last one will always be the default in your example. If not, see below.

You might have to run `qdat$from_date <- as.Date(qdat$from_date)` first.

Note: You were getting this result due to a weird thing from ifelse. From ?ifelse:

> ifelse() strips attributes
>
> This is important when working with Dates and factors

So we need to restore the class after the ifelse call.

First fix you original code by changing the ifelse to the correct call:

```
newqdat <- qdat %>% group_by(id) %>%
                    mutate(to_date = ifelse(fobs == 1,
                                            as.Date("2013-12-31"),
                                            as.Date(lead(from_date))))
```

And then change the class back to date:

```
class(newqdat$to_date) <- "Date"
newqdat
```